# How to calculate mean (or any other function) based on some criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I'm a complete newbie to R and I'm needing something that I'm not able to find. I think I don't know how to google it, so let me explain my problem. Lets suppose that I have a dataframe like this.

```
    criteria1    criteria2    data1    data2    data3
1           1          foo        2        1        3
2           1          foo        3        2        1
3           1          bar        2        1        3
4           2          foo        5        2        7
5           2          bar        8        2        3
6           1          bar        3        6        9
7           2          bar        2        5        6
8           3          xyz        2        5        6
```

I would like to calculate the mean of data1, data2 and data3, grouping by criteria1 and criteria2 and maintaining the dataframe structure (column names). The result should be something like:

```
    criteria1    criteria2    data1    data2    data3
1           1          foo      2.5      1.5        2
2           1          bar      2.5      3.5        6
3           2          foo        5        2        7
4           2          bar        5      3.5      4.5
5           3          xyz        2        5        6
```

So, I would like to know how to code this in R. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(criteria1, criteria2) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))

#Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#Groups: criteria1
#
#  criteria1 criteria2 data1 data2 data3
#1         1       bar   2.5   3.5   6.0
#2         1       foo   2.5   1.5   2.0
#3         2       bar   5.0   3.5   4.5
#4         2       foo   5.0   2.0   7.0
#5         3       xyz   2.0   5.0   6.0
```

Or

```
aggregate(cbind(data1, data2, data3) ~ criteria1 + criteria2, data = df, mean)
#  criteria1 criteria2 data1 data2 data3
#1         1       bar   2.5   3.5   6.0
#2         2       bar   5.0   3.5   4.5
#3         1       foo   2.5   1.5   2.0
#4         2       foo   5.0   2.0   7.0
#5         3       xyz   2.0   5.0   6.0
```

Comment: Hi beginneR. Thank you very much! Ins't there a way to do this without any library?

Comment: @davidbuzatto, I added another approach with base R

Comment: Note that this can also be accomplished with `plyr` (slower but more flexible than `dplyr`) and the completely unrelated `data.table`, which is, in my opinion, a superior solution for storing data that can be used as a general upgrade from `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 3):

Or using aggregate:

```
aggregate(df[ , 3:5], by = list(criteria1 = df$criteria1, criteria2 = df$criteria2), mean)
```

Comment: +1 Thankyou very much! I marked beginneR answer as as my solution since he updated his answer first, but you solution is great too!

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` solution.

```
require(data.table)

n <- 8

dt <- data.table(criteria1 = sample(3, n, replace = T),
                 criteria2 = sample(c("foo", "bar", "xyz"), n, replace = T),
                 data1 = sample(9, n, replace = T),
                 data2 = sample(9, n, replace = T),
                 data3 = sample(9, n, replace = T))

dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), keyby = list(criteria1, criteria2)]
```